# Excel - Find a Cell in an array and its location

Tags: arrays, excel, match, formula, lookup

Looking to figure out how to determine the address of a cell in an array based on a previously determined max value. See the attached picture:
[image: Sample Screenshot]
What I'm looking for in this image is the cell directly above the minimum value of 192.02. Total minimum value is determined by finding the minimum across the row, then down in a column. I need to figure out how to bolt on a formula that will essentially find that location and move up one cell. Duplicates aren't an issue - the first match is sufficient.

Comment: Its not very clear on what you're looking for. .please re-format the question with few example scenarios. Refer to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Haaaaa... I found out a method using SUMPRODUCT, but it wasn't working out for me, reporting a circular reference. I couldn't figure out what the hell the issue was until I realized the "row check" formula extended infinitely to the right and I'd put the formula in a cell in that area - thereby making it an infinite loop. Embarassing.

The method I found was this, incidentally:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((K6:M20=H24)*(COLUMN(K6:M20)))
=SUMPRODUCT((K6:M20=H24)*(COLUMN(K6:M20)))
```

Where H24 is my minimum value and K6:M20 is the range. Then you can use INDIRECT with these values to get the value of that cell. In my case, I'd use

```
 =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW-1,COLUMN),TRUE)
```

To find the cell directly above that value. Sometimes just posting a question can solve it for you, haha.